# param is missing or the value is empty: user when enabling password access to a page in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, password-protection, strong-parameters

I am getting this error: "param is missing or the value is empty: user" when I am trying to create password restricted access to user settings page in my app. All the logged in users can see a tab to change their two factor settings page. When they are click on the tab for two factor settings, they are required to enter the password for that account. I have a created page for password entry. However I keep getting the above error.

Here is the controller method defined inside two_factor_settings_controller.rb

```
def authorization_check_for_2fa
    @user = current_user
    prompt_for_password(current_user)
    if authorization_check_params[:password].present?
      debugger
      if current_user.valid_password?(authorization_check_params[:password])
        flash.now[:success] = "Yay correct password"
        redirect_to two_factor_settings_path
      else
        flash.now[:alert] = "Sorry, wrong password"
      end
    end 
  end
```

And these are the private methods in the controller:

```
 def prompt_for_password(user)
    @user = user
    session[:otp_user_id] = user.id
    render authorization_check_for_2fa_two_factor_settings_path
  end

 def authorization_check_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:password)
  end
```

The view page looks like this:

```
 .card.mb-3
    .card-header
      %h5.mb-0 Restricted access
    .card-body
      = simple_form_for @user, url: authorization_check_for_2fa_two_factor_settings_path,  html: { method: :post }  do |f|
        .form-inputs
          = f.input :password, input_html: { autocomplete: "current-password" }, required: true

        .form-actions
          = submit_button 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

Inside the route file:

```
  resource :two_factor_settings do
    get :authorization_check_for_2fa, on: :member
    post :authorization_check_for_2fa, on: :member
    get :regenerate_backup_codes, on: :member
  end
```

Would appreciate any clue to what is causing this error. thanks

Comment: Hi, how does the params looks in your terminal? issue could be related to strong params in rails. please add code snippet for `params` method if you have it in the controller.

Comment: It seems your error is raised from error `authorization_check_params` can you confirm? Can you show us the controller method that render your view with this html form?

Comment: @Abhinay I've added a debugger and here is what it returns in the terminal when I type params    ```(byebug) params
#<ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"two_factor_settings", "action"=>"authorization_check_for_2fa"} permitted: false> ```

Comment: @brcebn Yes, the issue is raised in the authorization check params method shown in the code snippets above. As you can see I have added it to require (:user) which is what's giving the error saying the value is empty for user. When I remove the require(:user) bit in the strong parameters it does work and display the password entry page. But after I submit a password comes with a different error `found unpermitted parameters: :utf8, :authenticity_token, :user` which doesnt make sense because earlier it said the value is empty for user.

Comment: According to your `params` values, there is not `user` key on your hash. This seems to come before your controller unless it has been remove somehow. Can you show us the value of `params` before `params.require(:user).permit(:password)`?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of [simple_form](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form), here is what your form should look like:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user, as: :user, method: :post, url: users_path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.submit 'New user' %>
<% end %>
```

The most important part in your case is `f.submit 'New user'`. You're submitting your form outside the form of the gem.